# RLY-8 POE relay using json

Tags: json

just got the DFrobot relay and trying to communicate with it using json commands 
pdf is [here](https://github.com/nxcosa/RLY-8-Relay-Controller/blob/master/RELY-8-POE-EN.pdf)

any help please how to send an on/off command from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty easy, just open a telnet to the device, an example:

```
telnet 192.168.1.10 2000
```

and copy paste one of the JSON commands from their [pdf](https://github.com/nxcosa/RLY-8-Relay-Controller/raw/master/RELY-8-POE-EN.pdf) document, like:

```
{"relay1":"on","relay2":"on","relay3":"off","relay4":"off","relay5":"off", "relay6":"off","relay7":"off","relay8":"off"}
```

and hit enter. In case if you want more than telnet commands you can check [this](https://github.com/aattila/relay8) Github project.

Answer (score 0):

please check : https://github.com/Dzduino/DFRobot-RLY-8-Web-Control/blob/master/index.php

You can use PHP Socket like bellow in an html or PHP page, please note that you have to use some local php server (Ex: XAMPP)  to test it:

```
<?php
    $addr = "192.168.1.10";     // RLY-8 Default Adress 
    $port = 2000;                // RLY-8 Default port 
    $timeout = 30;               // Connection Time out in Sec

    if (isset($_POST["cmd"])){  // check if a submit was done, otherwise the communicatino will start after page loading
        $cmd = $_POST["cmd"] ;  // Capture the input Command
        $fp = fsockopen ($addr, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout ); // initiate a socket connection 
        if (!$fp) {
            echo "($errno) $errstr\n"; // return the error if no connection was established
        } else {
            fwrite ($fp, $cmd);          // Send the command to the connected device
            echo fread($fp, 128);       // Echo the return string from the device
            fclose ($fp);               // close the connection
        }
    }
?>
```